# Calling C# program from another C# program

Tags: c#

I have 3 C# programs that need to be executed in an order(TestCSharp1, TestCSharp2 and TestCSharp3).2nd program should be executed only after first completes and 3 should execute only after 1 and 2 finish. How can I do this. Right now, I have them as scheduled tasks and I manually check if they have finished and then start others.

Comment: Why don't you make one program from them?

Comment: @Alexander, there are some calculations that has to happen in that order in each of these programs.

Comment: Doing calculations in a certain order is exactly what ONE program does. ONE program, not MANY. MANY programs may run concurrently, or one at a time, in every possible order, or not even ordered at all.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davethompson/archive/2011/10/25/running-a-scheduled-task-after-another.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Proccess` Class [(Documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) to start a process from inside your program. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
    class MyProcess
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Process myProcess = new Process();

            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start();
                myProcess.WaitForExit(); //use this if you want to pause execution of your program till the process you have started closes.
                // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself.  
                // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it  
                // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically 
                // from this application using the Kill method.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to notice `Process.WaitForExit()` given that the OP wants the other processes to complete first.

Comment: Ah good point. I will add it to the example

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are running command line programs you can create a batch file with the three executables in it and run the batch file as a scheduled task. As you'll see in the comments, if there are Windows programs this approach will not work.

E.g.

```
@echo off 
cd \ToTheRightPlace
TestCSharp1
TestCSharp2
TestCSharp3
```

You'll want to check return values, etc.

Comment: Incorrect. the batch file will run them all at the same time. This is not what the poster wants. The right approach is to use the Process and ProcessStartInfo classes in the System.Diagnostics namespace

Comment: A dos batch file runs one command at a time.

Comment: Sometimes, not always. depends on the program itself. For instance if I have 3 notepad.exe processes in a batch file, it will all run at the same time or even winword. At least it does on my system.

Comment: This is a far much better answer than any other in C#. Running programs is a OS task, not a development issue. So Batch is the way to go (or PowerShell)

Comment: Use "start" as in http://superuser.com/questions/103937/batch-file-running-application-in-order-vs-all-at-once

Comment: @AlG et al: if the executables are flagged as console applications then `cmd.exe` will wait, otherwise (it is a windows – GUI – application) it will not. Using `start /wait` in the batch file will force the former behaviour.

Comment: I disagree. This answer is good but I would approach the problem differently. I wouldn't have 3 separate apps. But if I had to have them, I would have either 1. programmed 1 to launch 2, programmed 2 to launch 3, when work is complete. Or 2: Have app 1 as main app and do all the work to determine if it's alright to proceed to launch next app, then do so. (use Process.Start for this, OP).

Comment: @jay_t55 I wouldn't have three separate apps as well, see my comments on the question...

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the discussion. I agree, I wouldn't go the 3 separate apps either, but given the OPs question it may not be an option.